# Как исключить дублирование при запросе сообщений в vk?

Tags: python, vkontakte-api, вконтакте, fastapi

Пытаюсь реализовать следующий функционал:

1. Организую получение новых сообщений через прослушивание сервера путем применения метода `groups.getLongPollServer`
2. Далее пытаюсь обработать это сообщение, выявить наличие ссылки и его удалить.

Однако, при реализации данной функции при отправке сообщения в беседу группы скрипт начинает получать неконтролируемое количество сообщений вместо одного уникального.

Пытался реализовать этот алгоритм несколькими методами в том числе `messages.getByConversationMessageId` но все равно получаем не одно сообщение а бесконечное множество.

Необходимо сделать так, чтобы при отправке сообщения в группу (будь то личные сообщения или сообщения в беседах) сервер получал только один отклик с одним уникальным сообщением и его обрабатывал.

```py
# /vk_api/vk_client.py

import aiohttp
import ssl
from typing import Dict, Any

async def get_long_poll_server(api_v, group_i, group_t) -> Dict[str, Any]:
    url = f"https://api.vk.com/method/groups.getLongPollServer?v={api_v}&group_id={group_i}&access_token={group_t}"

    # SSL context setup
    ssl_context = ssl.create_default_context()
    ssl_context.check_hostname = False
    ssl_context.verify_mode = ssl.CERT_NONE

    async with aiohttp.ClientSession(connector=aiohttp.TCPConnector(ssl=ssl_context)) as session:
        async with session.get(url) as response:
            return await response.json()

async def delete_message(api_v, group_i, group_t, peer_id, message_id):
    url = f"https://api.vk.com/method/messages.delete?v={api_v}&group_id={group_i}&access_token={group_t}&peer_id={peer_id}&message_ids={message_id}&delete_for_all=1"

    # SSL context setup
    ssl_context = ssl.create_default_context()
    ssl_context.check_hostname = False
    ssl_context.verify_mode = ssl.CERT_NONE

    async with aiohttp.ClientSession(connector=aiohttp.TCPConnector(ssl=ssl_context)) as session:
        async with session.get(url) as response:
            return await response.json()

def build_long_poll_url(server: str, key: str, ts: int) -> str:
    return f"{server}?act=a_check&key={key}&ts={ts}&wait=25"


async def get_message_by_conversation_message_id(api_v, group_t, peer_id, conversation_message_ids, extended=False, fields=None, group_id=None):
    url = f"https://api.vk.com/method/messages.getByConversationMessageId?v={api_v}&access_token={group_t}&peer_id={peer_id}&conversation_message_ids={conversation_message_ids}&extended={int(extended)}"

    if fields:
        url += f"&fields={fields}"
    if group_id:
        url += f"&group_id={group_id}"

    # SSL context setup
    ssl_context = ssl.create_default_context()
    ssl_context.check_hostname = False
    ssl_context.verify_mode = ssl.CERT_NONE

    async with aiohttp.ClientSession(connector=aiohttp.TCPConnector(ssl=ssl_context)) as session:
        async with session.get(url) as response:
            return await response.json()
```

```py
# /handlers/group_handlers.py

import aiohttp
import ssl
from vk_api.vk_client import get_long_poll_server, build_long_poll_url, delete_message, send_long_poll_ack, get_message_by_conversation_message_id
import re
from settings import group_token, group_id, api_version
import logging
import asyncio


async def sleep(delay: float):
    await asyncio.sleep(delay)


async def process_long_poll_response_group(update, unique_messages_group):
    if "type" in update and update["type"] == "message_new":
        message_id = update["object"]["message"]["id"]
        peer_id = update["object"]["message"]["peer_id"]
        if message_id not in unique_messages_group:
            unique_messages_group.add(message_id)
            message_text = update["object"]["message"]["text"]
            cmids = update["object"]["message"]["conversation_message_id"]
            links = re.findall(r"(?i)\b(?:https?://|www\.)\S+\b", message_text)
            if links:
                logging.info(f"Message contains links, deleting message_id={message_id}, peer_id={peer_id}")
                await delete_message(api_version, group_id, group_token, peer_id, message_id)
                return
            logging.info(f"Received a new message from the group: {message_text}")

            # Получаем информацию о сообщении по conversation_message_id
            response = await get_message_by_conversation_message_id(api_version, group_token, peer_id, cmids)
            if "response" in response and "items" in response["response"]:
                for item in response["response"]["items"]:
                    # Обработка информации о сообщении
                    # В item содержится информация о сообщении, такая как текст, отправитель и т. д.
                    # Вы можете добавить здесь свою обработку полученной информации
                    pass


async def long_poll_group(group_id, group_token, api_version):
    unique_messages_group = set()  # Create a set to store unique message IDs

    long_poll_url = ""
    last_ts_group = 0

    logging.info("Starting Long Poll...")

    response_data = await get_long_poll_server(api_version, group_id, group_token)
    server = response_data["response"]["server"]
    key = response_data["response"]["key"]
    ts = response_data["response"]["ts"]
    long_poll_url = build_long_poll_url(server, key, ts)

    ssl_context = ssl.create_default_context()
    ssl_context.check_hostname = False
    ssl_context.verify_mode = ssl.CERT_NONE

    while True:
        async with aiohttp.ClientSession(connector=aiohttp.TCPConnector(ssl=ssl_context)) as session:
            async with session.get(long_poll_url) as response:
                data = await response.json()
                if "failed" in data:
                    if data["failed"] == 1:
                        ts = data["ts"]  # Update ts value
                        new_long_poll_url = build_long_poll_url(long_poll_url.split('?')[0], key, ts)
                        long_poll_url = new_long_poll_url
                    elif data["failed"] == 2 or data["failed"] == 3:
                        continue
                    else:
                        logging.error("Unknown error")
                elif "updates" in data:
                    for update in data["updates"]:
                        logging.info(f"Received Long Poll update: {update}")
                        await sleep(2)  # Добавляем задержку 1 секунду перед обработкой каждого обновления
                        await process_long_poll_response_group(update, unique_messages_group)
```

```
2023-07-26 00:20:27,724 - root - INFO - Starting the application...
2023-07-26 00:20:27,725 - root - INFO - Starting Long Poll...
2023-07-26 00:20:35,422 - root - INFO - Received Long Poll update: {'group_id': XXXXXXXX, 'type': 'message_new', 'event_id': 'xkxlxkxlkxlkxlkxl', 'v': '5.131', 'object': {'message': {'date': 1690320035, 'from_id': 98682, 'id': 0, 'out': 0, 'attachments': [], 'conversation_message_id': 19, 'fwd_messages': [], 'important': False, 'is_hidden': False, 'peer_id': 10000, 'random_id': 0, 'text': 'вщзолдво'}, 'client_info': {'button_actions': ['text', 'vkpay', 'open_app', 'location', 'open_link', 'callback', 'intent_subscribe', 'intent_unsubscribe'], 'keyboard': True, 'inline_keyboard': True, 'carousel': True, 'lang_id': 0}}}
2023-07-26 00:20:37,425 - root - INFO - Received a new message from the group: вщзолдво
2023-07-26 00:20:38,096 - root - INFO - Received Long Poll update: {'group_id': XXXXXXXX, 'type': 'message_new', 'event_id': 'xkxlxkxlkxlkxlkxl', 'v': '5.131', 'object': {'message': {'date': 1690320035, 'from_id': 98682, 'id': 0, 'out': 0, 'attachments': [], 'conversation_message_id': 19, 'fwd_messages': [], 'important': False, 'is_hidden': False, 'peer_id': 10000, 'random_id': 0, 'text': 'вщзолдво'}, 'client_info': {'button_actions': ['text', 'vkpay', 'open_app', 'location', 'open_link', 'callback', 'intent_subscribe', 'intent_unsubscribe'], 'keyboard': True, 'inline_keyboard': True, 'carousel': True, 'lang_id': 0}}}
2023-07-26 00:20:40,710 - root - INFO - Received Long Poll update: {'group_id': XXXXXXXX, 'type': 'message_new', 'event_id': 'xkxlxkxlkxlkxlkxl', 'v': '5.131', 'object': {'message': {'date': 1690320035, 'from_id': 98682, 'id': 0, 'out': 0, 'attachments': [], 'conversation_message_id': 19, 'fwd_messages': [], 'important': False, 'is_hidden': False, 'peer_id': 10000, 'random_id': 0, 'text': 'вщзолдво'}, 'client_info': {'button_actions': ['text', 'vkpay', 'open_app', 'location', 'open_link', 'callback', 'intent_subscribe', 'intent_unsubscribe'], 'keyboard': True, 'inline_keyboard': True, 'carousel': True, 'lang_id': 0}}}
2023-07-26 00:20:43,033 - root - INFO - Received Long Poll update: {'group_id': XXXXXXXX, 'type': 'message_new', 'event_id': 'xkxlxkxlkxlkxlkxl', 'v': '5.131', 'object': {'message': {'date': 1690320035, 'from_id': 98682, 'id': 0, 'out': 0, 'attachments': [], 'conversation_message_id': 19, 'fwd_messages': [], 'important': False, 'is_hidden': False, 'peer_id': 10000, 'random_id': 0, 'text': 'вщзолдво'}, 'client_info': {'button_actions': ['text', 'vkpay', 'open_app', 'location', 'open_link', 'callback', 'intent_subscribe', 'intent_unsubscribe'], 'keyboard': True, 'inline_keyboard': True, 'carousel': True, 'lang_id': 0}}}
```